# Importing a Filepath from a File in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript function in multiple HTML files with a local path reference like this:

```
varFileObject = fso.OpenTextFile("F:\\Process\\logs\\log_ex.csv", 8, true,0);
```

Is it possible to store the value `F:\\Process\\logs\\log_ex.csv` in a seperate file and read it when the html is opened, so I dont have to change every file each time I want to adjust the path?

(I cant use PHP)

Comment: Where are you doing this? In Node?

Comment: It´s in the <script> </script> part of the HTML Files

Comment: If you've got an ActiveX to work on your page, then it is possible, with the exact same command. Just change the path and switch `8` to `2`, and then do `varFileObject.Write("...")`. Notice, that all this will work in IEs only, and also only when the security options are set to allow the use of ActiveX.

Comment: Are you using jquery ? you create a javascript file apart from your js where you put you path as a variable. Then you include your js file in your pages and it's done. you can use you variable in your files.

Comment: perfect JBO. this works for me. thank you